# Ayudita plox, no me compila esta cosa xd

Tags: c

me pueden ayudar con la línea de mi código, quiero meter ese tipo de entradas pero me arroja estos errores:

```
main.c:29:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘else’
   29 |     else if (num = 3)
      |     ^~~~

main.c:31:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
   31 |         printf("No es suficiente \n");
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.c:32:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
   32 |         printf("*La serpiente te ataca y caes abatido* \n");
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.c:33:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
   33 |         printf("Tu senda de guerrero acaba aqui \n");
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.c:38:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘if’
   38 |     if (resp=='n') {
      |     ^~
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int num;
        char resp;
                   
        printf("Te encuentras en un valle pantanoso \n");
        printf("*Aparece una serpiente de 4 cabezas* HP: 200 \n");
        printf("Quieres atacar? (s/n)\n");
        scanf("%c", &resp);     
                    
        if (resp=='s') {
         printf ("Elige tu ataque!\n");
         printf("1.Bola de fuego: 200atk \n2.Corte: 100atk \n3.Salmuera: 150atk \n");
         printf("Con que habilidad quieres atacar?: \n");
          scanf("%d", &num);
        
        if (num = 1)
         printf("%d Has bajado 200HP a la serpiente \n", num);
         printf("Has derrotado a la serpiente \n"); /*quiero introducir este tipo de líneas pero me arroja error*/
            
        else if (num = 2)
         printf("%d Has bajado 100HP a la serpiente \n", num);
            
        else if (num = 3)
         printf("%d Has bajado 150HP a la serpiente \n", num);
            
        
    }
    
        
        else 
         printf("No has seleccionado una acción...");
         
        if (resp=='n') 
         printf("Has escapado...");
```

Comment: Te faltan muchas llaves `{ }`.

Comment: `=` es operador de asignación. Para comparar usa `==`. Luego de un if debe haber un bloque de código rodeado por llaves: `if (condicion) { instruccion1; instruccion2; }`. Solo si el bloque consiste de una sola instrucción, puedes omitirlas: `if (condicion) instruccionUnica;`. Eso debería resolver todos o al menos la mayoría de los problemas.